# Продолжить нумерацию в enumerate после использования continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Не пойму как продолжить нумерацию с той же цифры, если мы пропустили значение с помощью continue. 
Пример кода

```
for num, i in enumerate(['a','b','c','d','e','f'], start=1):
    if i == 'c':
        continue
    print('{}. {}'.format(num, i))
```

В этом случае нумерация будет 1,2,3,5,6 минуя 4. А нужно, чтобы 4 не была пропущена.
Могу, конечно, до цикла ввести переменную, а потом считать количество итераций, добавляя по еденице, но может есть более красивое решение.

Comment: @MaxU 
       ` if i !='c': print('{}. {}'.format(num, i))?`

тогда то же самое. Или я что-то не понял.

Comment: Да, это я сглупил... Врядли  здесь получится обойтись без дополнительной переменной

Comment: @MaxU тоже так думаю, но решил "а вдруг".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

по-моему здесь вообще не нужна конструкция `enumerate()`, вместо этого можно воспользоваться дополнительной переменной-счетчиком:

```
i = 1
for c in items:
    if c == 'c':
        continue     
    print(f'{i}. {c}')
    i += 1
```

или:

```
i = 1
for c in items:
    if c != 'c':
        print(f'{i}. {c}')
        i += 1
```

Comment: Да, вероятно, все-таки так и сделаю. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: x != 'c', ['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
for num, i in enumerate(filtered, start=1):
    print('{}. {}'.format(num, i))
```

Comment: Спасибо! На самом деле я даже не подумал о таком решении, единственное я здесь я лишнего насчитаю, по сути ради нумерации пробегаешь не один раз, а два.

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi Уже писал, нет никакого двойного прохода. filter – это генератор, который выполняется лениво. Т.е. выдает символ только в тот момент, когда его запросит for/enumerate. Попробуйте представить его как функцию с yield и сами поймете.

Answer (score 1):

Можно отбор вынести из тела цикла, как-нибудь так:

```
for num, i in enumerate((x for x in ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] if x != 'c'), start=1):
    print('{}. {}'.format(num, i))
```

Т.е. по сути подавать на вход `enumerate` уже готовую последовательность, без "ненужных" элементов.

Comment: по-моему, это не очень удачный совет - уж лучше воспользоваться дополнительной переменной, чем добавлять еще один (лишний) проход по оставшимся элементам списка...

Comment: @MaxU Это генератор. Никаких лишних проходов. Мой вариант с фильтром, тоже генератор.

Comment: @Lecron, я не вижу смысла использовать дополнительный цикл (будь то `list comprehension`, `generator` или явный цыкл), если нет острой необходимости его использовать... Вариант с единственной дополнительной переменной выглядит явно эффективнее. Или я что-то упустил из виду?

Comment: @MaxU Возможно вы правы. У меня наверное сформировалось списковое мышление. Постараюсь исправится.

Comment: @MaxU, все зависит от задачи, на самом деле. В данном случае, конечно, нет смысла отдельно подготавливать данные, но если подготовка достаточно сложна, имеет смысл перенести ее в отдельную функцию-генератор, а в цикле уже обрабатывать готовые данные.

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Но как правильно написал @MaxU это дополнительные лишние проходы. У меня задача шире, чем пример, который я выложил, поэтому будет дополнительная загрузка. Но все равно решение крутое)

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi, как уже сказал Lecron, лишнего прохода не будет. Из списка берется число, сразу проверяется на соответствие, сразу передается в enumerate, и сразу передается в цикл. Так с каждым числом из списка. Вы бы описали более подробно задачу, тогда стало бы понятнее, подойдет вам это решение или нет.